# モバイルにて、アプリがインストールされていたらアプリへの移動を促す方法

Tags: ios, swift, ruby-on-rails

iPhoneでweb(Chrome)でサービスを開いているときに、もしもユーザーが同じサービスのアプリをインストールしていたらアプリへ誘導、していなかったらアプリのダウンロード画面へ誘導させたいです。
以下の方法を考えているのですが、より簡単な方法はありますでしょうか？

1. url-schemeを用いて、ユーザーがアプリをダウンロードしているか否かを調べる
2. ダウンロードしていたらアプリへの遷移画面を出す。していなかったらAppStoreに移動する

url-schemeの取得方法、アプリへの遷移方法はこれから調べる予定です。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Smart App Bannersの機能を使うのが簡単だと思います。

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/PromotingAppswithAppBanners/PromotingAppswithAppBanners.html

以下のように所定の形式のmetaタグを記述しておくことで、ほぼおっしゃっているような挙動が実現できます。（アプリケーションがインストールされていれば開く、そうでなければAppStoreを開く）

メタデータを渡すこともできるので、Webサービスの状態によって起動したアプリケーションの画面を変える、ということも可能です。（アプリケーション側で実装する必要があります）

```
<meta name="apple-itunes-app" content="app-id=myAppStoreID, affiliate-data=myAffiliateData, app-argument=myURL">
```

Comment: そのような機能があったのですね。
ありがとうございます！利用してみます！